# Toggle visibility between two A HREF when clicking one of them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tubular

To put it as simple as possible.

I have one

```
<a href="#" id="PAUSE" class="tubular-pause">Pause</a>
```

and a second

```
<a href="#" id="PLAY" class="tubular-play">Play</a>
```

I only want *PAUSE* visible at first, but once it’s clicked it disappears and *PLAY* becomes visible and so on and so on and so on (toggle)...

It's the classes *tubular-pause* and *tubular-play* that are the triggers for the actual pausing and playing of my video. Therefor the action of the clicking need to stay intact and occur before the “toggling” I guess.

Thank you!

Comment: @AmitJoki Just edited, please take a look again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it without jquery, this is pretty easy:

```
function onButtonClick () {
  var playButton = document.getElementById("play");
  var pauseButton = document.getElementById("pause");

  if (pauseButton.style.display == "none") {
    pauseButton.style.display = "block";
    playButton.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    playButton.style.display = "block";
    pauseButton.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

[Demo on codepen.](http://codepen.io/djmadeira/pen/FrGcx)

Comment: Thank you! Action when clicking is still there. Though, I changed from 'block' to 'inline' instead.

Answer (score 1):

Just use this:

```
$('#PLAY').hide();
$('#PAUSE').click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $('#PLAY').show('fade');
});
$('#PLAY').click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $('#PAUSE').show('fade');
});
```

Demo: <kbd>http://jsfiddle.net/fDmLR/</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery like this:

```
$("#play").onlclick(function(){
   $("#play").fadeOut(0);
   $("#pause").fadeIn(0);
});
$("#pause").onlclick(function(){
   $("#pause").fadeOut(0);
   $("#play").fadeIn(0);
});
```

Sorry if it is not working, I'm still beginner ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery toggle. For example

```
$( "#play" ).click(function(){
  ButtonToggles();
});

 $( "#pause" ).click(function(){
   ButtonToggles();
 });

function ButtonToggles(){
   $("#pause").toggle();
   $("#play").toggle();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hide()` to hide the `#Play` anchor by default and use `.toggle()` to toggle between show and hide between two anchors:

```
$('#PLAY').hide();
$('#PLAY, #PAUSE').click(function () {
    $('#PLAY, #PAUSE').toggle();
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zB87X/)**